# Sanitize email html body and increase zoom level HTML

Tags: html-email, svelte, email-client, sanitize

I am making an email client for blind people (well, legally blind anyways), and I am trying to render the HTML body for the emails, in a safe way, but without losing the style of the original content. I also want all the content to have increased the size of everything, especially the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using an `iframe` which can prevent script execution via the `sandbox` attribute. You can add additional styling to set a specific root font size, though this may not work as expected depending on the mail's own styling.

```html
<script>
    let mail = `
        <h1>Title</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        
        <!-- Svelte parser does not like additional script tags. -->
        <${''}script>alert('!')</${''}script>
    `;
    
    $: document = mail + `
        <style>
            html, body { font-size: 32px; }
        </style>
    `
</script>

<iframe srcdoc={document} title="Mail message" sandbox />

<style>
    iframe {
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/eafd6cac8b854663b7e729c309a3bfda?version=3.49.0)

As an alternative to the font size, the whole frame can be scaled up using a transform, its size has to be reduced proportionally:

```css
iframe {
    border: none;
    width: calc(100% / 2);
    height: calc(100% / 2);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7544e028e5bd4b7bb34087caa9cff8cf?version=3.49.0)

---

If you need more direct access to the the generated content, e.g. via events, you can instead sanitize the HTML using one of the various libraries out there (e.g. `xss` or `sanitize-html`). The HTML can then be inserted using `{@html ...}`.

To handle a click on a link, you can wrap the content in an element and handle the click there, checking whether the `target` was a link element.

```html
<script>
    let mail = `
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
    `;
    
    function sanitize(html) {
        // Use some sanitizer package here
        return html;
    }
    
    function onClick(e) {
        if (e.target.tagName == 'A') {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Links to: ' + e.target.href);
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="container" on:click={onClick}>
    {@html sanitize(mail)}
</div>

<style>
    .container {
        border: none;
        width: calc(100% / 2);
        height: calc(100% / 2);
        transform-origin: 0 0;
        transform: scale(2);
    }
</style>
```

(Sanitization omitted, because the mentioned packages are not compatible with the REPL.)

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/479c574f99d040538f0dadaa2b8f9ba2?version=3.49.0)

Comment: Thank you, but using this setup, it is not possible to do a javascript action when the user presses a link?

Comment: Inside the frame? Might be a bit tricky. You could maybe inject code and only allow that to run using `Content-Security-Policy`.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use `Content-Security-Policy`?

Comment: You would need to set the `csp` attribute of the iframe to only allow scripts with a specific `nonce`.  The attribute is currently not supported in all browsers, so that approach might be not that great. I added another alternative that does not use `iframe`.